# Add azure SQL user with terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

is there a possibility to add a sql user to the azure sql via terraform?
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5242/adding-users-to-azure-sql-databases/

Or is there a better suggestions how to create a SQL user?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes you can do it from Terraform if that is what you want to happen. I would use a [null resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/null/resource.html) provider in Terraform to execute the commands from the box that is running Terraform. You could use PowerShell, CMD, etc. to connect to the database after it is created and create your user account. Here is an [example](https://www.phillipsj.net/posts/how-to-handle-unsupported-azure-features-in-terraform) of how to use the null resource provider.

I would image it would look something like this, in this example I am using the [SqlServer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/?view=sqlserver-ps) PowerShell module.

```
resource "null_resource" "create-sql-user" {

  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "Add-SqlLogin -LoginName ${var.loginName} -LoginType ${var.loginType}"
    interpreter = ["PowerShell", "-Command"]
  }

  depends_on = ["azurerm_sql_database.demo"]
}
```

You could of course do it with our CLI tools, but this would guarantee it is part of your Terraform deployment.

Comment: Then I prefer to do it in power shell directly

Comment: @Jamie : how do you connect to the SQL Server, before firing the powershell command?

Comment: How would you you add a password as well using only the command?

Comment: @CaioGomes checkout the LoginPSCredential option in the docs. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sqlserver/add-sqllogin?view=sqlserver-ps

Comment: I saw this documentation @Jamie, but to use this I would need several commands and this null_resource option permits only one, right? Or am I missing something? I solved this issue adding a powershell script to my pipeline after the server is created by terraform. The script adds the users.

Comment: @CaioGomes you can alter the command to execute a script. so instead of -Command you could do  -File and pass a file name. You will need to set the working_dir property or use releative paths.

Comment: I see, that's handy. Thanks!

Comment: This is very useful!

Comment: This is awful. This isn't doing it using Terraform at all, this is just using Terraform to run a script. There's isn't even any guarantee that the environment Terraform is running in will have the necessary SQL module installed.