# How to terraform import all resources within a resource group?

Tags: azure, import, terraform

I need to import all resources within a resource group **without having to identify them individually** using terraform import.

I already tried to import the resource group to see if it will import its resources, using the following command:

```
 terraform import "azurerm_resource_group.example" "/subscriptions/*****/resourceGroups/rg-example"
```

Here is my main.tf file:

```
terraform {
required_providers {
    azurerm = {
        source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
        version = "3.56.0"
    }
    }
}

provider "azurerm" {
    features {
    }
}

resource azurerm_resource_group example{
   name = "rg-example"
}
```

This resource group has three storage accounts, however, only the resource groups is imported.

Is there another way to do this?

Thank you

Comment: LMGTFY https://github.com/Azure/aztfexport

Comment: I tried this. After logging in to azure with `az login` and running the command `aztfexport rg rg-example` I get the error "Access is denied to the requested resource. The user might not have enough permission.". However, my user is the owner of the subscription. Do you have any idea why this is happening

Comment: You executed the command to import the RG, and the RG was imported as expected according to the question. Is there some confusion over the command functionality that the belief was that additional resources beyond the RG would be imported? If so, then the doc would probably be helpful: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/cli/import

Comment: @MattSchuchard, the command `terraform import` is working as it should, yes. I was looking for a similar command but instead of just importing the resource group, it also imports its resources without having to identify them individually. Thank you for the help

Answer (score 1):

No terraform command supports importing multiple resources at the same time. But still, we can use scripts to do that.

To import multiple resources, first download all the resource details in a CSV file from Azure.
[image]

[image]

Now I used the below Powershell script to import all three resources in an Excel sheet at a single time.

```
# Path to the CSV file
$csvFilePath = "C:\Users\v-goonav\Downloads\Azureresources (6).csv"

# Import the CSV file
$table = Import-Csv -Path $csvFilePath

# Filter the records based on the "TYPE" column
$resources = $table | Where-Object { $_.TYPE -eq "Storage account" }

# Import the names of the storage accounts
Write-Host "Importing Storage account"
foreach ($account in $resources) {
    #Write-Host $account.NAME
    $name=$account.NAME
    Write-Host $name
    terraform import azurerm_storage_account.$name /subscriptions/00000-00000-0000-00000-000000000/resourceGroups/testrgtf/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/$name
}

$resources = $table | Where-Object { $_.TYPE -eq "Virtual network" }

# Import the names of the vnet
Write-Host "Importing vnet"
foreach ($account in $resources) {
    #Write-Host $account.NAME
    $name=$account.NAME
    Write-Host $name
    terraform import azurerm_virtual_network.$name /subscriptions/00000-00000-0000-00000-000000000/resourceGroups/testrgtf/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/$name
}
```

[image]

You can use this Powershell script in terraform. Please check the below reference links.

1. [null resource | Terraform](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/mildred/null/latest/docs/resources/null_resource)
2. [Getting terraform null_resource local-exec to run a PowerShell install-module | Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59057132/getting-terraform-null-resource-local-exec-to-run-a-powershell-install-module)