# Add azure SQL Server login using terraform

Tags: sql-server, azure, terraform

Is it possible to add an user as active directory admin for an azure sql server using terraform?

https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/sql-database/sql-database-aad-authentication

I need this to be enable users to authenticate through their company logins to a sql server created using Terraform.

I've found this question:

[Add azure SQL user with terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54326033/add-azure-sql-user-with-terraform)

But it is not what I need, it creates a new user for a login. Terraform docs regarding azure do not document this action.

https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/sql_server.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please reference this link: [Active Directory Admin for azurerm_sql_server](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-azurerm/issues/3348):

Support for configuring Azure Active Directory Administrators for a SQL Server Database can be found in the [azurerm_sql_active_directory_administrator resource](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/sql_active_directory_administrator.html).

**azurerm_sql_active_directory_administrator:**

Allows you to set a user or group as the AD administrator for an Azure SQL server.

**Example useage:**

```
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "acceptanceTestResourceGroup1"
  location = "West US"
}

resource "azurerm_sql_server" "example" {
  name                         = "mysqlserver"
  resource_group_name          = "${azurerm_resource_group.example.name}"
  location                     = "${azurerm_resource_group.example.location}"
  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = "4dm1n157r470r"
  administrator_login_password = "4-v3ry-53cr37-p455w0rd"
}

resource "azurerm_sql_active_directory_administrator" "example" {
  server_name         = "${azurerm_sql_server.example.name}"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.example.name}"
  login               = "sqladmin"
  tenant_id           = "${data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id}"
  object_id           = "${data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id}"
}
```

Hope this helps.