# Basic SQL commands in Terraform

Tags: sql-server, azure, terraform

I am using Terraform to build an Azure DB and set the correct Azure AD Admin etc - all working well.

I now need to create

```
CREATE LOGIN [XXX-XXX] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
CREATE USER [XXX-XXX] FOR LOGIN [XXX-XXX];
ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [XXX-XXX]
```

Any ideas if this is possible within Terraform - thinking its the easiest way as the user is already authorised to create the database.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54523391/2626613 would be a good start.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add azure SQL user with terraform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54326033/add-azure-sql-user-with-terraform)

Comment: The examples use 'Add-SqlLogin' however the problem is for 'LoginType'...

"At this time, the cmdlet does not support ExternalUser or ExternalGroup."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its ***not possible to directly run the commands*** that you have mentioned in the question but ***you can use `Invoke-sqlcmd` and authenticate with your AAD admin credentials and run the commands*** .

**I tested the scenario with the below code :**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features{}
}
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}
resource "azurerm_sql_server" "example" {
  name                         = "ansumansqlserver"
  resource_group_name          = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                     = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  version                      = "12.0"
  administrator_login          = "admin"
  administrator_login_password = "password"

  tags = {
    environment = "production"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "example" {
  name                     = "ansumansacc"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_sql_database" "example" {
  name                = "ansumansqldatabase"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  server_name         = azurerm_sql_server.example.name

  extended_auditing_policy {
    storage_endpoint                        = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_blob_endpoint
    storage_account_access_key              = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key
    storage_account_access_key_is_secondary = true
    retention_in_days                       = 6
  }
  tags = {
    environment = "production"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_sql_active_directory_administrator" "example" {
  server_name         = azurerm_sql_server.example.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  login               = "sqladmin"
  tenant_id           = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id           = data.azurerm_client_config.current.object_id
}
## creating Login in master database first
resource "null_resource" "master"{
provisioner "local-exec"{
  command = <<EOT
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId "<SubscriptionID>"
$token = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl https://database.windows.net).Token
Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance ${azurerm_sql_server.example.fully_qualified_domain_name} -Database master -AccessToken $token -Query "CREATE LOGIN [user@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER"
EOT
interpreter  = ["PowerShell", "-Command"]
}
depends_on=[
  azurerm_sql_active_directory_administrator.example,
  azurerm_sql_database.example
]
}
## creating the user from the login created in master and assigning role
resource "null_resource" "database"{
provisioner "local-exec"{
  command = <<EOT
Set-AzContext -SubscriptionId "<SubscriptionID>"
$token = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl https://database.windows.net).Token
$query= @'
CREATE USER [AJAY] FOR LOGIN [user@tenantname.onmicrosoft.com];
GO
ALTER ROLE [db_datareader] ADD MEMBER [AJAY];
GO
'@
Invoke-SqlCmd -ServerInstance ${azurerm_sql_server.example.fully_qualified_domain_name} -Database ${azurerm_sql_database.example.name} -AccessToken $token -Query $query
EOT
interpreter  = ["PowerShell", "-Command"]
}
depends_on = [
  null_resource.master
]
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

**Note:** Please make sure to have ***[`Azure Powershell Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-7.1.0)*** and ***[`SQLServer Powershell Module`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/download-sql-server-ps-module?view=sql-server-ver15)***.